# How can I validate data form input html with restAPI

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
   [
    [
    "#Cats6789Staplers"
    ],
[
"#Cats6789Punching Machine"
],
[
"#Cats6742Scissors"
]
]
```

this is my scrpit

```
$("#procode").on("keyup", function(e) {

   let procode = $('#procode').val(),
   
   $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8082/product/procode",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
                    
          if(response==procode){
            $('#msg').show();
            $('#msg').html("ProductCode already taken").css("color", "red");
            $('#submit').hide();
          }else{
            $('#submit').show();
           }
            
        },
         error: function(xhr, status, error) {
         console.log(error);
    }
                    
 });


})
```

That I want to get data form user input after that get this data to check with data API when if Duplicate we hide btn_submit(submit)

Comment: Assuming that the ajax request works.
Before the ajax use the $('#submit').hide() the submit should only be visible AFTER you confirmed that there is no dublicate.